# ¿como autenticar un cliente con una app externa con mi api Users? con ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

lo que quiero hacer es una validación que una app externa haga login  y pueda enviarme mediante post  el correo y contraseña   y yo validar que existen y mandarles un mensaje de acceso concedido o error

en mi modelo usuario  tengo una validación de que no se repita el correo en app/model/user.rb

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
validates :email, uniqueness: { scope: :email,
    message: "el correo ya ha sido registrado" }


end
```

tengo mi base de datos asi
`app/db/schema.rb`

```
  create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "name"
    t.string "surname"
    t.string "cel"
    t.string "email"
    t.string "password"
    t.string "password_recovery_token"
    t.datetime "password_recovery_expiration"
    t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false
  end
```

Comment: ¿has probado con [devise](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise) u otra gema de autenticación? En general, cuando tengas una necesidad específica sobre alguna funcionalidad que extrañes en rails, puedes buscar en [ruby-toolbox](https://www.ruby-toolbox.com) o [awesome-ruby](https://github.com/markets/awesome-ruby) que lo más probable es que alguien ya haya creado alguna gema que cubra tus necesidades. Saludos

Comment: gracias amigo lo consultare en las paginas gracias por compartir las